# kotlin lazy initialized property can not be modified in init block

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor

I have some properties in my class which are initialized lazily. I want them to be immutable which is why I don't use `lateinit` and I don't want them to be nullable, so I think lazy is the best option here.

in the `init` block of my class, I want to modify one of the properties but it gives me the compilation error: `Variable 'mLstQuestions' must be initialized`.
I understand that lazy properties are initialized as soon as they used, so why this is happening? how can I fix this? what is the better approach?

if I create a function `Initialize()` and modify it in that function. it's perfectly ok and I can call it in the init block.why is that? does this work fine? what is the difference? if doing something like this is forbidden in the `init` block, shouldn't function call be forbidden too?

**This is my  code:**

```
class CharacterListView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    parent: ViewGroup
) {
    init {
        mLstQuestions.adapter = mQuestionsListAdapter
        // error : Variable 'mLstQuestions' must be initialized
        // error : Variable 'mQuestionsListAdapter' must be initialized
    }
    
    private val mLstQuestions by lazy { findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.char_list) }
    private val mQuestionsListAdapter by lazy { QuestionsListAdapter(getContext(), this) }
    private val mRootView by lazy { inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false) }
...
}
```

and this is the code with initialize function:

```
class CharacterListView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    parent: ViewGroup
) {
    init { initialize() } // no errors!

    private fun initialize() {
        mLstQuestions?.adapter = mQuestionsListAdapter
    }

    private val mLstQuestions by lazy { findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.char_list) }
    private val mQuestionsListAdapter by lazy { QuestionsListAdapter(getContext(), this) }
    private val mRootView by lazy { inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false) }
...
}
```

Comment: By the way there's no need of defining lazy variables when you are using them at init block, it is redundant.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to define the `init{ }` block after the `declaration` of your variables.

```
class CharacterListView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    parent: ViewGroup
) { 
    private val mLstQuestions by lazy { findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.char_list) }
    private val mQuestionsListAdapter by lazy { QuestionsListAdapter(getContext(), this) }
    private val mRootView by lazy { inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false) }

init {
        mLstQuestions.adapter = mQuestionsListAdapter
    }
}
```